# Pagination configuration for Angular Material issues

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have introduced pagination and followed the [guides](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination).

Here is my `app.component.ts` file -

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { ApiServicefile, User } from './api.service';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  //providers: [ ApiServicefile ],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  error: any;
  title = 'toms-app';
  //users: User;
  users = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'username', 'email'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

constructor(private apiServicefile: ApiServicefile) { }


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiServicefile.getUser()
    .subscribe(
      (data: User) => this.users = data, // success path
      error => this.error = error // error path
    );
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.users.paginator = this.paginator;
} 

}
```

In HTML file the material table was previously populated by `users: User`

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="users">
```

I have now introduced an error on this line for `this.users`:

```
(data: User) => this.users = data, // success path

ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(27,23): error TS2322: Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'MatTableDataSource<User>'.
    src/app/app.component.ts(27,23): error TS2740: Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'MatTableDataSource<User>': _data, _renderData, _filter, _internalPageChanges, and 18 more.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, tried various things.

UPDATE(Change to TS file, no longer getting errors but pagination not working):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { ApiServicefile, User } from './api.service';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  //providers: [ ApiServicefile ],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  error: any;
  title = 'toms-app';
  users: User;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'username', 'email'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

constructor(private apiServicefile: ApiServicefile) { }


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiServicefile.getUser()
    .subscribe(
      (data: User) => this.users = data, // success path
      error => this.error = error // error path
    );
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
} 

}
```

Comment: Did you try removing that users = new MatTableDataSource<User>(); and define users as an array.

Comment: I need MatTableDataSource to validate pagination

Comment: Try defining MatTableDataSource<User> as <any>

Comment: Create a interface `User` with the properties

Comment: Try changing to dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User[]>();

Comment: What is the latest HTML and TS Code?

Comment: @OronBen-David got me onto something. Changed all refs to <User[]> including in my service file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking all User references as an array `<User[]>` did the trick. However I have lost the use of `error` in my `ngOnInit()`:

```
//error => this.error = error, // error path
```

Any ideas on above?

Answer to pagination as follows:

app.component.ts -

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { ApiServicefile, User } from './api.service';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  //providers: [ ApiServicefile ],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  error: any;
  dataSource: any;
  title = 'toms-app';
  users: User[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'username', 'email'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

constructor(private apiServicefile: ApiServicefile) { }


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiServicefile.getUser()
    .subscribe(
      (data: User[]) => {
        this.users = data; // success path
      //error => this.error = error, // error path
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      });
}

}
```

app.service.ts -

...

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiServicefile {
  userUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/users/20';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUser() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl)
      .pipe(
        retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
        catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
      );
  }
```

...